# Cesiumjs Particle System Blending

Tags: cesiumjs

I feel like this is a fairly basic question, but i haven't found any real information online. how can i set the blending state to additive for a cesium particle system for an effect such as fire, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not available in the current version.

Particle systems in Cesium are implemented as collections of Billboards, and currently the Billboard system is hard-coded to [always use alpha blending](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/927b4bf2915e6a76b7194a92f3ccdd2e7c6eede9/Source/Scene/BillboardCollection.js#L1728).  It would be a great feature to add though, but it would take some plumbing work to make an option for additive-blended billboards, and then another option for additive-blended particle systems that call for additive billboards.  Both would be useful in their own right.

Comment: Wow, i'm rather shocked. Everywhere they mention particle systems they use examples that almost always use additive blending. Anyway, thank you for a definitive answer!

Comment: Yeah, hopefully someone will open a PR someday with additive options for both billboards and particles (and maybe PointCollection as well).  The enum for it is available at the `RenderState` level, it just needs to be requested at the graphics primitive level.